# Running Yocto on Raspberry Pi CM4

Tags: yocto, raspberry-pi4, yocto-recipe

I have recently got a CM4 and after experimenting with standard builds now I am trying to run Yocto on it. I have tried running Yocto on Raspberry Pi 4 and it worked fine. However on CM4 it is not working. CM4 can not find bootable image and keeps rebooting after running out of options.

There is no target machine specific to CM4 that I could find. I read somewhere that as it is based on Raspberry Pi 4, "raspberrypi4-64" should work fine as target machine. However it didn't work for me.

Is it due to the difference that RPi4 boots from SD Card and CM4 from eMMC? Or I am supposed to use different process to flash the image?

I am relatively new to Raspberry Pi world and any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

I have tried to create Yocto builds from different and relatively new branches but all of them ended up with similar results.  I doubt CM4 just doesn't detect generated Yocto image. I have tried wic and tar also but didn't work.

Comment: After experimenting with a few branches, I figured out that honister was the one that worked on CM4 without any issues. dunfell is too old and anything beyond honister was giving cam related error.